# how to set local redis repository in helm?

Tags: artifactory, helm3, tyk

I try to install Redis for [tyk](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk-helm-chart) with my company's local jfrog repository but I am facing the following issue.
I am using Helm v3.8.2.

```
helm install redis tyk-helm/simple-redis --set image.repository=images.artifactory.mycompany.com/redis -n tyk
Error: unknown flag: --set image.repository
```

can you help me figure out how to solve this issue? I am new to using helm.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be complaining of an unknown flag `image.repository`. Did you try running the command written [here](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-self-managed/tyk-helm-chart/#redis)

> helm install tyk-redis bitnami/redis -n tyk

Comment: That will not work because in some companies you don't have access to the internet. so what we can do is download the chart, and upload the chart to the repo. then whenever we want to use it download the chart by curl in the same folder we want to run the helm and instead of bitnami/redis use that chart zip file.